# Transforming CCYYMMDD date format to DDMMYYYY format with Spark SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, date-formatting

I need to do a transformation on a Dataframe column containing dates in Spark. The column is originally formatted by defining the century (CCYYMMDD) and I want to change it to a different format (DDMMYYYY).

For example:

"21000101" to "01012000"

or

"20991231" to "31121999"

I have tried to use the spark sql function date_format:

```
public static Column toFlatFileDate(Column c, String inFormat, String outFormat) {
        return functions.date_format(functions.to_timestamp(c, inFormat), outFormat);
    }
```

```java
Dataset<Row> result = source.withColumn("transformedDate", toFlatFileDate(source.col("base"), "CCyyMMdd", "ddMMyyyy"));
```

The expected output should be that the "transformed-column" column should be of form ddMMyyyy but the result is a null value.

Comment: Peculiar format. So would the 21 in `21000101` refer to the century from 2001 to 2100 inclusive?

Comment: Century: 21, Year in century: 00, Month: 01, Day: 01

Comment: Century: 20, Year: 99, Month: 12, Day: 31